# Deploy web application from visual studio to azure virtual machine IIS Server

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to publish a Web Application from Visual Studio to IIS configured on an Azure Virtual machine.

I am getting this error from Visual Studio when I am trying to publish remotely:

> *******Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("xyzzzzzzz.azure.com"). On the remote computer, make sure
>   that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web
>   Management Service") is started.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.)*********

I was able to publish my application locally from inside the Virtual Machine.

I have configured IIS inside the virtual machine and set all the inbound rules and outbound rules in the Azure portal.

The error says I need to install Web Deploy and check that Web Management Service is started.

I have checked already and both the services are running.

I have no idea now why this is not working.

Comment: Are you able to deploy this to a web app, to test access and connectivity?

Comment: I only have Virtual machine for this web application on Azure. but i have deploy locally to IIS inside the VM to check access and connectivity.

Comment: Is the Web Management Service on the VM started?

Comment: Yes both Web Management Service and Web Deployment Agent Service are started and running on VM.

Comment: I have figured it out this whole process of deploying Web application from remote computer visual studio to IIS inside Azure VM . Thanks everyone for support.